# ¿Como obtener un valor de una clase entidad y asignarlo a una variable en asp.net c# 3 capas?

Tags: c#, asp.net, revisión-de-código

Hola espero me puedan ayudar y orientar si lo que hago es una buena practica de antemano gracias por su ayuda.

En cuanto a mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un proyecto en 3 capas mas la capa e entidades.

Necesito pasar solo un valor consulta que recibe un parámetro a una variable, mi código si funciona pero no se si es la mejor manera de hacerlo.

En mi capa de Acceso a Datos este es mi codigo.

```
       Entidad_Usuario uEntidad = new Entidad_Usuario();     

       public Entidad_Usuario Consulta_Datos(string Usuario)
    {
        DataSet datos = new DataSet();
        DataTable datos_usuario = new DataTable();
        SqlParameter sqlparameter = new SqlParameter("@Usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        sqlparameter.Value = Usuario;            

        //Aqui solo llamo mi procedimiento almacenado.
        datos = _conexion.ExecuteDataset("sp_Obtener_personas", sqlparameter);

       // Asigno los valores a mis variables de entidad
        datos_usuario = datos.Tables[0];
        DataRow row = datos_usuario.Rows[0];           
        uEntidad.Nombre_usuario = Convert.ToString(row[1]);
        uEntidad.Puesto = Convert.ToString(row[2]);
        uEntidad.Ubicacion = Convert.ToString(row[3]);

        return uEntidad;

    }
```

Este en el código en la capa de Lógica de Negocio

```
 public EUsuario Consultar_Datos(string usuario)
    {
        return conexion.Consulta_Datos(usuario);        
    }
```

En mi capa presentación tengo esto lo cual no se si es correcto.

```
 string usuario = "Pedro";
 string puesto = t.Consultar_Datos(usuario).Puesto;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En base a la experiencia, podría sugerirte que utilices una variable de tipo `Entidad_Usuario` para obtener la información de tu consulta.

```
Entidad_Usuario entidadUsuario = new Entidad_Usuario();
string usuario = "Pedro";
entidadUsuario = t.Consultar_Datos(usuario);
```

¿Por qué?

Porque, ¿qué sucede si luego necesitamos obtener la ubicación?
Podemos hacer esto:

```
 string usuario = "Pedro";
 string puesto = t.Consultar_Datos(usuario).Puesto; 
 string ubicacion = t.Consultar_Datos(usuario).Ubicacion;
```

Lo cual funciona, pero realizamos dos llamadas a la base de datos con idénticos parámetros e idénticas salidas, cuando podrías hacer una sola llamada y obtener los datos en un objeto.

En este momento solo necesitas el puesto, pero **los sistemas cambian constantemente** y la idea es **preparar tu código para que sea lo mas sencillo de mantener** de cara al futuro.

Adicional, ¿qué sucede si el usuario no existe? Sería conveniente agregar el control de excepciones y lectura de datos vacía en tu método `Consulta_Datos(string Usuario)` para informar en la capa de presentación del o los posibles problemas que podrían darse, y si no hay ningún problema, entonces si continuar con la asignación al objeto.

Comment: Hola @JYass muchas gracias por tus recomendaciones lo implementare como me lo indicas.